# Is there a way to edit .scss files in Bootstrap's precompiled library?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, sass

I'm working on the front-end of a project that had already progressed a decent amount before I joined. The project uses Bootstrap's precompiled library, so I don't have any access to the scss files. This means I can't find them at *all* in my folder.

[bootstrap directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD4Ar.png)

The bootstrap directory is pretty much the one above. I've tried making changes in the css files such as bootstrap.css, but it doesn't work. The changes appear to be saved in the file, but when I run the project and inspect element, I see it referencing back to the scss files with the original code.

[inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufFVc.png) [edited bootstrap.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbDV7.png)

I'm currently using Visual Studio to edit my files. I've tried putting my own stylesheet after the bootstrap ones in the  to overwrite the boostrap stylesheet, but no luck.

Is there any way I can:

- access the scss files to edit them
- have my own stylesheet overwrite the boostrap one
- or just make changes to the bootstrap.css file

Is it plausible to install the version of bootstrap with the scss and replace the precompiled version mid-project?

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting the boostrap with your own stylesheet is probably the safest way to go and totally doable you just need to add your own classes and then get super nested into them to override bootstrap. It can take alot of trial and error.

> Is it plausible to install the version of bootstrap with the scss and replace the precompiled version mid-project?

I have done this before without too much trouble but it could cause issues if you change the bootstrap version or if someone previous had already customized it. In the later case you'd have to make sure to reflect those changes.
If you decide to go this route here is an awesome bootstrap customizer a co-worker made. https://github.com/rachaelshaw/bootstrap-4-customizer